# Python SentiStrength binary score outputs only 1 score

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am currently working on text analysis using SentiStrength python library by command `result = senti.getSentiment(cs, score='binary')`. Firstly, I run it in Jupyter notebook and it works well. It outputs 2 scores which are positive and negative sentiment scores such as `[(2,-1)]`. However, when I try to run it in anaconda prompt or spyder. It outputs only 1 values like `[1]` and I do not understand why. I guess it is because I run it on different environment. I would like to ask how could I run this command in anaconda prompt or other IDE so that it could output result correctly? or did I do something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if score == 'scale': # Returns from -1 to 1
        senti_score = [sum(senti_score[i:i+2])/4 for i in range(0, len(senti_score), 3)]
    elif score == 'binary': # Return 1 if positive and -1 if negative
        senti_score = [1 if senti_score[i] >= abs(senti_score[i+1]) else -1 for i in range(0, len(senti_score), 3)]
    elif score == 'trinary': # Return Positive and Negative Score and Neutral Score
        senti_score = [tuple(senti_score[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(senti_score), 3)]
    elif score == 'dual': # Return Positive and Negative Score
        senti_score = [tuple(senti_score[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(senti_score), 3)]
    else:
        return "Argument 'score' takes in either 'scale' (between -1 to 1) or 'binary' (two scores, positive and negative rating)"
    return senti_score
```

was having the same problem and took at look at the sourcecode and found the documentation error. You should use 'dual' for the score type.